# Spam and anti-virus on Exchange 2007?

Tags: untagged

I've found a number of solutions. They all say that they're the best (of course they do!) but they all can't be so I'd like some impartial advice.

I would like to know your experiences of spam and anti-virus software before I make a purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Sort-of an obtuse answer, but I've had very good luck using an outboard service. I have used spamstopshere.com but I believe google also has an equivalent service with their recently acquired postini. Anything that simply jacks in as as your SMTP relay will be very easy to set up and provide some extra value as an MX backup.

Outsourcing anti-spam/anti-virus entirely eliminates the need to keep the software up-to-date etc, but does leave you open to the potential of an in-office virus outbreak.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer 3rd-party services.  I've used (and have been very happy with) Postini (Google's offering) and MXLogic.  I hardly ever see SPAM using either for myself or my clients.

When the SPAMMERS figure out a new trick, it doesn't take long for these guys to update their filtering algorithms.  It can get pretty costly (either in maintenance contracts or admin time) doing this on your own server unless you are in a very large enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

I second (or third) the benefit of using a 3rd party service to kill spam and viruses before they ever make it to your network.  If you get the Enterprise CAL for Exchange 2007, this is included through Exchange Hosted Services (by Microsoft)

This is what you get: http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/exchange-online-hosted-email.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Have you had any personal experience with exchange hosted services? I also saw this on my travels.

Comment: I do, but I work for Microsoft, so I don't want to come across as a corporate shill :)  Hopefully someone else with experience will hop on and share.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.safentrix.com. It has paid as well as Free services and practically plug-n-play with minimal maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Symantec Mail Security appliance and found they work very well with high accuracy and can have AV added.  All mail is scanned before entering the network so no load on the Exchange system.  I have heard they now offer this as a VMware Virtual Machine so if you have a VMware environmemt, install is easy and no hardware to buy.